# Оценка сложности O() для getElementsByClassName, getElementsByTagName, querySelector, кто знает?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, сложность

Подскажите сложности этих методов (javascript) в нотации O() (о большое). Если знаете сложности еще каких- то методов тоже пишите, помогла бы даже ссылка на материалы, в которых это расписано.